# Android Download Manager setDestinationInExternalFilesDir

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am using the Download Manager and when I use

```
 setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "example.ext");
```

the files are downloaded to Android/data/com.example.app/files/Download folder.

When I try

```
setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/folder", "example.ext");
```

I get: 
`IllegalStateException: Cannot create directory mnt/sdcard/folder`. 
I've set the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission too.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Add the permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `absolute` path for ExternalFileDir

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String folder = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/YourFolder" ;
File dir = new File(folder );
if (!dir.exists()) {
if (dir.mkdirs()) {
    Log.i(Tag,"Directory  Created");
    }
}
```

I guess this might even work for you.

Comment: I tried the following.
downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(v.getContext(), folder, down.getTitle()+".epub"));

But the file gets downloaded to 
file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.app/files/*folder-path*

Comment: I temporarily fixed it by moving the file after downloading from the Android/data/com.example.app/files to the directory I required.

Comment: I fixed my problem by using this command: request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(destinationDirectory,fileName + fileExtension))); Where destinationDirectory is String destinationDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder/"

Answer (score 1):

use `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/folder", "FileName.extention");`

this worked for me..

Comment: Probably just because my version is much more recent than this post, but I had to add the context, so request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(this, "/folder", "Filename.extension");

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem by using this command:

```
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(destinationDirectory,fileName + fileExtension)));
```

Where destinationDirectory is

```
String destinationDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder/"
```

Comment: this giving me this error    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67932843/w-downloadmanager-aborting-request-for-download-17-failed-to-create-target-fil?noredirect=1#comment120073691_67932843

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission like

//region [ PERMISSION ]

```
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public static boolean CheckPermission(final Context context){
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if( currentAPIVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

//endregion
```