# W/DownloadManager: Aborting request for download 17: Failed to create target file /storage/emulated/0/Ringtone/Fav_Ringtone.mp3

Tags: android, android-download-manager, download-manager, internal-storage, android-internal-storage

I am trying to download my mp3 file and want to save it to internal storage at a specific location.

But every time my download is failing.

> Logcat error message

```
01-01 08:36:09.295 154-748/android.process.media W/DownloadManager: Aborting request for download 
17: Failed to create target file /storage/emulated/0/Ringtone/Fav_Ringtone.mp3
```

> Download Method

```
   public void Save_mp3_internal_Storage(Uri uri,Context context){

        String destination = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Ringtone/";

        Delete_mp3_internal_Storage(new File(destination,"Fav_Ringtone.mp3"));

        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
                .setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(destination,"Fav_Ringtone.mp3")))
                .setTitle("Ringtone Downloading")
                .setNotificationVisibility(1);
                 manager.enqueue(request);
    }

    public void Delete_mp3_internal_Storage(File file){
        if (file.exists()){
            file.delete();
        }
    }
```

I think it is an emulator fault. because most of the time my emulator fails to download the files(SmartGaga)

Comment: Ringtones......

Comment: What android version are you trying? Did you give storage read/write permission?

Comment: @SyedAfeef I added read and write permission to my manifest. Api leval 30

Comment: It's best practice to download files into Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS for the latest android
And did you give permission to the app? just writing it in manifest won't grant the permission. goto app permission and set it to allowed.

Comment: @Syed Afeef The DownloadManager does not need those permissions.

Comment: `Ringtones` !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @blackapps What do you want to say through Ringtone!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I did not say ringtone or Ringtone. I said: Ringtones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to this

```
    public void Save_mp3_internal_Storage(Uri uri, Context context){

        Delete_mp3_internal_Storage(context);

        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context,Environment.DIRECTORY_ALARMS,"Fav_Ringtone.mp3")
                .setTitle("Ringtone Downloading")
                .setNotificationVisibility(1);
                 manager.enqueue(request);
    }

    public void Delete_mp3_internal_Storage(Context context){
       File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_ALARMS),"Fav_Ringtone.mp3");
       if (file.exists()){file.delete();}
    }
```